# Using private static nested class to implement Singleton

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am currently learning about the Singleton pattern. I learnt that the classic way to implement it is to create a static field of the Singleton class type, hide the constructor using private access modifier, and provide a public `getInstance()` method.

However, I thought of another way of implementing it without using private constructors:

```
public class SWrapper {
    private static Singleton holder = new Singleton();
    private static class Singleton{ /* implementation without private constructor*/}
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return holder;
}
```

QUESTION: Does this implementation work? (I think it does but I can't be sure.) If it does, are there any advantages or disadvantages to using this implementation?

Comment: `Singleton` is private!

Comment: "Does this implementation work?" Have you tried?

Comment: @fabian it should be

Comment: use an enum for singletions, but don;t use singletons

Comment: Can you tell us what are the advantages of your implementation? Why do you think it is better than the other approach? Otherwise I don't see a question here..

Comment: @NimChimpsky Have you ever tried to access members declared in a *private* class from outside that class or the containing class, even *public* ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a singleton, but it's eagerly initialized (not lazily initialized), so it's not that interesting. Your use of the name `holder` suggests you are attempting the [*Initialization-on-demand holder idiom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom):

```
public class Singleton {
    private static class Holder {
        static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton ();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private Singleton () {
    }
    // rest of class omitted
}
```

which initializes the singleton instance when first got (rather than when class is loaded), yet doesn't require any special synchronization to be threadsafe.

Comment: _when first got_ vs _rather than when class is loaded_ is really only one method invocation deeper (unless you're using the `Singleton` class for something else).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis not quite; any *reference* to the class (ie import) is when the class loads, which can be hours before it's *used*. Eg your controller might come up, but no one calls it for ages.

Comment: An `import` statement does nothing at runtime.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what i meant was if a class A references - ie *uses* - class B, then class B is loaded when class A is loaded. This means the OP's singleton will likely be initiaized at JVM startup

Comment: _used_ as defined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1). If the only use is invoking `getInstance`, then using your solution and using the one provided (minus the `private`) in OP's question are essentially the same.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis no: with OP code the singleton will be initialized when the class that calls `getInstance()` is *loaded*, whereas with my code the singleton will be initialized when the `getInstance()` method is *first called*

Comment: Sure, but if there's nothing else in OP's `Singleton`, invoking `getInstance` is the only thing (minus some reflection) that can cause `Singleton` class to be loaded.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you are completely missing the point: with OP code the singleton will be initialized when any class is **loaded** that refers to (ie has coded a call to any method (static or instance) or refers to any field) - **whether or not any calls are actually made**. So even if the singleton is as coded (ie empty), it will be initialized when the class that has the call to it is loaded

Comment: No, it won't. `Singleton` will be loaded when the method is invoked. See the link from the JLS. Copy [this](http://ideone.com/u9SFbE) into an IDE and run it.

Comment: Yay, nay? They don't really gain anything, here.

Comment: @sotir yay. I ran my own test, and you're correct. There's an "edge case" of access to a static field or method (not the getter) that would load the class before calling the getter, but most singletons don't have such things.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work, since your `Singleton` class is private. That means you don't have access to it's members from outside `SWrapper` (except for those defined in `Object` of course).

Answer (score 0):

public class SingletonWithHelper {

```
private SingletonWithHelper(){}

//This is the most widely used approach for Singleton class as it doesn’t
//require synchronization.
private static class SingletonHelper{
    private static final SingletonWithHelper SINGLETON = new SingletonWithHelper();
}

public static SingletonWithHelper getInstance(){
    return SingletonHelper.SINGLETON;
}
```

}